# Facebook login in MVC 3 - Razor

Tags: asp.net-mvc, facebook, asp.net-mvc-3

I would like to log into my site using Facebook login. I have downloaded a Facebook helper and a code sample from http://facebookhelper.codeplex.com/releases/view/53840.

When I click on the login button, I get an error:

> OAuth2 specification states that 'perms' should now be called 'scope'. Please update."

I have registerd my site in developer Facebook and added an `appid` and a secret code. What else do I need to do?

Answer (score 0):

you must download 2 required dll , 
1-WebMatrix.WebData.dll
2-WebMatrix.Data.dll 
 and put them in bin folder, and use it in facebook helper into app_code folder